# how to convert my html string into its own datatype?

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm fairly new to JS and HTML. Working on a Django project now makes me crazy about it.

I have passed a variable from the context from Django toward html. I noticed the datatype of the data is converted to string by default.

views.py:

```
context = {'segment': 'index', "service_data": data }
html_template = loader.get_template('index.html')
return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))
```

HTML pages

```
<div class="card-body">
  <canvas id="myAreaChart" width="100%" height="40"></canvas>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  const service_data = "{{ service_data }}"
</script>
```

In Javascript, I can see the datatype of service_data is a string. I'd like to traverse it as an array, but it is converted to a string.

```
const data = Array.from(service_data);  //this is converted to object not array.

function prepareChartData(data) {
    var chartData = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        let timestampe = data[i][0]
        let dat_list = data[i][1]
        chartData.push([timestampe, dat_list]);
```

My service_data is a fairly large data from django backend, hence, I do not want to use split or something to convert it.

---

The **service_data** snippet:

Please ignore those &gt, etc, not sure why HTML added them, but image the data itself is a very nested dictionary.

```
[(datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 4, 18, 35, 1, 247336, tzinfo=&lt;UTC&gt;), [[{&#x27;kubernetes_pod_name&#x27;: &#x27;kafka-rawbus-bravo-3&#x27;, &#x27;value&#x27;: 7.5456592756413645}, {&#x27;kubernetes_pod_name&#x27;: &#x27;kafka-rawbus-bravo-5&#x27;, &#x27;value&#x27;: 6.988051860579239}, {&#x27;kubernetes_pod_name&#x27;: &#x27;kafka-rawbus-bravo-0&#x27;, &#x27;value&#x27;: 11.394453190010722}, {&#x27;kubernetes_pod_name&#x27;: &#x27;kafka-rawbus-bravo-7&#x27;, &#x27;value&#x27;: 7.905077155911794}, {&#x27;kubernetes_pod_name&#x27;: &#x27;kafka-rawbus-bravo-4&#x27;, &#x27;value&#x27;: 7.792379308708253}, {&#x27;kubernetes_pod_name&#x27;: &#x27;kafka-rawbus-bravo-14&#x27;, &#x27;value&#x27;: 10.292450756795946}, {&#x27;kubernetes_pod_name&#x27;: &#x27;kafka-rawbus-bravo-1&#x27;, &#x27;value&#x27;: 6.355755419836891}, {&#x27;kubernetes_pod_name&#x27;: &#x27;kafka-rawbus-bravo-15&#x27;, &#x27;value&#x27;: 14.111596406948182}, {&#x27;kubernetes_pod_name&#x27;: &#x27;kafka-rawbus-bravo-16&#x27;, &#x27;value&#x27;: 13.40657800705202}, {&#x27;kubernetes_pod_name&#x27;: &#x27;kafka-rawbus-bravo-2&#x27;, &#x27;value&#x27;: 6.015374411354142}, {&#x27;kubernetes_pod_name&#x27;: &#x27;kafka-rawbus-bravo-9&#x27;, &#x27;value&#x27;: 7.047300820373079}, {&#x27;kubernetes_pod_name&#x27;: &#x27;kafka-rawbus-bravo-17&#x27;, &#x27;value&#x27;: 12.68578754440751}, {&#x27;kubernetes_pod_name&#x27;: &#x27;kafka-rawbus-bravo-8&#x27;, &#x27;value&#x27;: 7.800883809244761}...]
```

Can you please suggest:

1. A way to make sure the context I passed to HTML is the original datatype (such as a list)?
2. If the context is the default string, what is proper way to convert this to string into a nested array so I can traverse for charts?

Comment: it sounds like you should send it as a JSON string in your context, then you can use `JSON.parse` in Javascript to get the appropriate Javascript data structure.

Comment: Thanks Robin.  I got some advice on that too. Given the data is not json, it seems not easy to deserilized for javascript.

Comment: Do you think JS have other way to parse data other than json?

Comment: not built-in. You could try to write your own parsing function, but I seriously don't recommend it. I'm not sure what is in your Python data that can't be easily translated to JSON by using `json.dumps`. (If it's the datetime objects, you can easily convert those to either date strings or numeric timestamps in Python, and then decode them as such in Javascript.)

Comment: OK，yes. I just reformat my results data and make it json. I can now traverse it properly in JD now.